# Flat a nested expression

Tags: prolog

I wanto to translate expressions like `X = a(b(c(d)))` in `[a, b, c, d]`.

I guess i have to iterate/recurse the operator `=..`, but i don't know how. I tried

```
flatten([], []).
flatten(Exp, X) :- Exp=..[H,T], flatten(T, Y), X is append([H], Y).
```

but it does not seem to work.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[flatten](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.12%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/lists.html%27%29%29)/2 is a built in usually, while [is](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28is%29/2)/2 introduces arithmetic evaluation. Thus your Prolog should warn you about these problems in your code.

If you are limiting the expression to unary terms, the code should be simplified (note I renamed the procedure):

```
flatterm(Exp, [H|R]) :-
    Exp =.. [H, T],
    !, flatterm(T, R).
flatterm(T, [T]).
```

test:

```
?- flatterm(a(b(c(d))),X).
X = [a, b, c, d].
```

You should try to understand why I swapped the base/recursive case, and the role of the `!` (also known as [cut](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=!/0)).

Comment: Just a question: which is the name of the `=..` operator?

Comment: it has a strange name: [univ](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28%3D..%29/2). I think was meant for something like 'universal accessor'...

Comment: @Aslan986 btw usual notation of predicates in Prolog include arity, and operators are surrounded by `(` and `)`: `(=..)/2`